# Extend menu xhtml file in a core project used by clients

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2, xhtml

I am developing a core application that will be used by different clients. Every client will use this core application. This application will have a xhtml file that will be a extension of a menu.
It means that the core application (core war) will contain a basic menu. But this menu can be extended for every client.

How can I include a file that the clients have to create in their project and fill it to extend the menu?

The files will be like:

```
Core Project
 \_ src
     \_ main
       \_ resources
          \_ META-INF
             \_ resources
                 \_ menu.xhtml

Client's Project
 \_ src
     \_ main
        \_ resources
           \_ META-INF
               \_ resources
                  \_ extendedMenu.xhtml
```

And the clients will can extend the menu's core adding html in extendedMenu.xhtml.

I have tried directly:`<ui:include src="/extensions/menuExtender.xhtml"/>` but the resource is not found.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the solution. The problem was the file path in the client's project.

I have changed the file and I put into:

```
Client's Project
 \_ src
    \_ main
       \_ webapp
          \_ extensions
             \_ extendedMenu.xhtml
```

and in the core project only instanciate like:

```
<ui:include src="/extensions/extendedMenu.xhtml"/>
```

and works perfectly.

Comment: Yes, it was a misspelling also. Thank you